# any API to send mail on WinCE 5.0

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce

any API to send mail on WinCE 5.0?

Comment: Thank you, ctacke and ho1. Here I find more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636698/cf-net-smtp-pop3-clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/sdf) has a [Mail namespace](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/7e16eccb-dc9e-4559-c79c-cfaad631ac15.htm).  Be forewarned that we never implemented attachments (it not too hard to do, but we never got around to it).

Answer (score 0):

Since [WinCE 5.0 supports Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886481.aspx) you could just send the emails using standard [SMTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). I don't think `System.Net.Mail` will be available, but you can just connect using normal sockets and then send the data as described in the SMTP RFC.